# Vue - How to pass data from main.js to *.vue using props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

everyone. Sorry, for my dumb question, but I've tried a lot to do.
What I want to do is pass result of getUser() function to my Home.vue app.
But first, I tried to pass simple variable 'counter' using props:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

export default new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  el: '#app',
  props: { 'counter': 1 },
  template: '<app v-bind:counter="counter" />',
  components: { App },
  created () {
    // fetch the data when the view is created and the data is
    // already being observed
    this.getUser()
  },

  methods: {
                getUser() {
                    fetch('/api/auth/user/user/')
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => console.log(data));
                }
            },
});
```

Home.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  #app
    .card(v-for="profile in profiles")
      .card-header
        button.btn.btn-clear.float-right(@click="deleteProfile(profile)")
        .card-title {{ profile.user }}
        
      .card-body {{ profile.phone_number }}
      .card-body {{ profile.address }}
      .card-body {{ counter }}

</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'profile-list',
  computed: mapGetters(['profiles']),
  props: ['counter'],
  methods: {
    deleteProfile (profile) {
      // Вызываем действие `deleteNote` из нашего хранилища, которое
      // попытается удалить заметку из нашех базы данных, отправив запрос к API
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteProfile', profile)
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    // Перед тем как загрузить страницу, нам нужно получить список всех
    // имеющихся заметок. Для этого мы вызываем действие `getNotes` из
    // нашего хранилища
    this.$store.dispatch('getProfile')
    
  },

}
```

What I want to do is print 'counter' under profile.address but this doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any initialisation of counter. Just change `props: { 'counter': 1 }` to `data () {return { 'counter': 1 }}`

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Can you upvote and accept the answer? Thanks @Chainsaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any initialisation of counter. Just change your code from
`props: { 'counter': 1 }` to

```
data () {return { 'counter': 1 }}
```

Learn more: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#data